# Vue3 how to bind custom event to specific component in router-view?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

this is my App

```html
//App.vue
<template>
  <Header ref="header"></Header>
  <RouterView @emitDelet="deleteHeader"> 
  </RouterView>>
  <Footer></Footer>
</template>
```

this is my route, `router-view`contains three components.

```js
[
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      showFooter: true,
    },
  }, //
  {
    path: '/search',
    name: 'search',
    component: Search,
    meta: {
      showFooter: true,
    },
  },
  {
    path: '/Login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login,
    meta: {
      showFooter: false,
    },
  }
]
```

I only want to bind custom event to `search` component, how should I do.
If I bind it to `router-view`,I need to `defineEmits` in every component to avoid warning in devtool although it doesn't affect work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the best approach is to use the [`inject/provide`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#provide-inject) pattern :

in `App.vue` :

```html
<template>
  <Header ref="header"></Header>
  <RouterView> 
  </RouterView>>
  <Footer></Footer>
</template>
<script setup>
import { provide } from 'vue'

function deleteHeader(){
//....
}

provide('deleteHeader',deleteHeader)

</script>
```

in  Search component :

```html
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'

const deleteHeader = inject('deleteHeader')

//then you could run it like `deleteHeader` instead of emit('emitDelet')
</script>
```